# bcp for Linux fails when importing very small data value, such as "-1.28212683287E-308"

Tags: sql-server

Using the Linux version of the bcp utility to import data into SQL Server (SQL Server 2016).  And, the import fails on data row with an extremely small data value in one of the columns, such as "-1.28212683287E-308".

We are migrating from Sybase ASE (v12.5.1) to SQL Server 2016.  And, we are migrating an existing data import process which loads large amount of data from data file (with millions rows of daa) that loads data into a database on a Sybase ASE 12.5.1 system to SQL Server 2016.

The process currently runs successfully and without issues on Sybase ASE, including when loading data with very small values such as "-1.28212683287E-308".

But, the same process fails when importing data with very small values, such as "-1.28212683287E-308", into SQL Server 2016.

However, there is no issue performing the same data load, with the very small data values such as "-1.28212683287E-308", using the Windows version of Linux.

The following is the bcp command-line used to perform the data-load:

```
/sales/mssql-tools/bin/bcp chireldatadb..xe_data in /logs/tmp/isql.sh_data_20191009_124320_ld-atl-syn0gs_43025.bcp -e /tmp/in.chireldatadb..xe_data.err -b 1000 -D -S LAMSQL1 -U ###### -P ###### -c -r '|\n' -t '\|'
```

Comment: "using the Windows version of Linux"??? I assume you mean the Windows version of sql server? Even so, that string converts to 0 on Windows which I assume is what is causing your error. select convert(float(53), '-1.28212683287E-308')

Comment: You'll have to decide what you actually want to happen with these values. `-1.28212683287E-308` is too small to be represented by SQL Server's `float`, as that does not support denormalized values. If accepted, it must be rounded to 0. Probably the best approach is to make sure you're not relying on which version(s) of `bcp` decide to round and why, but copy from a view instead that rounds these unrepresentable values to 0 before they get to the import. If you are *not* importing into a `float` column, it's an issue internal to `bcp`. What error do you get?

Comment: Incidentally, insofar as the range of `float` is concerned, the behavior should be identical whether you're using SQL Server on Windows or on Linux -- the difference should only be in `bcp`, which is doing the actual data load. If you do find a behavioral difference, MS would likely consider that a bug that needs fixing. (They might consider the `bcp` difference a bug that needs fixing too, but if so it would at least be a less important one.)

Comment: Thanks for the response and the catch.  Sorry, I meant to type "using Windows version of bcp" (not "using Windows version of Linux").

Comment: A couple of additional info:

Comment: I have a couple of important additional info.  First, the data type of the column into which the very small data values, such as the example "-1.28212683287E-308", is 'float' data type.  Second, float fully supports storage of these tiny data values.  And, I have confirmed these 2 different ways.  First, the data value is able to be stored in the 'float' typed column using SSIS.  And second, the tiny data values is also able to be loaded and stored in the 'float' typed column using the Windows version of the bcp utility.  As a result, the issue is not with SQL Server, but with Linux's bcp.

Comment: OK, tested it myself. SQL Server 2016 and 2017 both handle denormal floats correctly -- if you can get them into the tables; the native parsing routines do not support them (you can't produce a `CAST` or `CONVERT` expression that will yield them directly from their string representations, but they can be the result of calculations). I withdraw my statement that they're not supported; this was based on a report of someone having trouble feeding them through TDS to a SQL Server 2012 instance, but I can't replicate that myself right now.

Comment: OK, using a minimal repro I can confirm that the Linux version of `bcp` does not handle denormal values for floats. It simply gives "invalid value for cast specification" -- at least not when run from a container, the situation may vary depending on the distro you're running. I suspect, but cannot easily confirm, that it was compiled without support for denormal floats, and the conversion fails in the C standard library. The smallest normal value (2^-1022) is accepted when input as `2.2250738585072014E-308`.

Comment: My suggestion would be to [report this](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/). A prompt resolution is not to be expected from that; if you need that I recommend opening an issue with Microsoft Support. The workaround would be to use something other than the Linux `bcp` to bulk load the data. Unfortunately, SQL Server's own `BULK INSERT` statement or `OPENROWSET(BULK)` provider can *not* be used, because they will convert these values down to 0, using the same logic the server uses in `CAST` / `CONVERT`.

Comment: Thank you for your responses.  We have conducted extensive internal testing regarding this issue and have confirmed that this is simply a defect with Microsoft's Linux bcp.  And, we have also confirmed that this continues to be an issue with the newer version of Linux bcp.  The updated release of Linux bcp continues to fail on the discussed data values.  So, for now, we are the following 2 things.  First, we are opening a support case with Microsoft regarding defect with the Linux bcp.  And, in the mean-time, we are looking at other tools for processing and loading the small data values.

Comment: Additionally, during our internal testing, we confirmed that the Windows version of bcp actually supports the processing and loading of a broader range of floating point data values that is greater than which is 'officially' documented as the ranges of floating point data values that SQL Server supports.  Specifically, Windows bcp supports loading of floating point data values from -4.94065645841247E-324 from -0 side to 4.94065645841247E-324 from +0 side.  Conversely, the 'official' documentation states support of from -2.23E-308 from -0 side to 2.23E-308 from +0 side.